# How to see hidden content in html selectors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When I want to show view source it looks like this:

```
<li class="results__list-container-item"></li>
```

But when I click Inspect Element in Firefox I see something like this:

```
<li class="results__list-container-item"><div class="offer offer--normal"><a class="offer__click-area" href="/praca/data-engineer-for-bixby-voice-assistant-krakow,oferta,7201566"></a><div class="offer__info"><div class="offer-details"><div class="offer-logo"><a href="https://pracodawcy.pracuj.pl/company/18797776/profile" class="offer-logo__link"><img src="https://i.gpcdn.pl/oferty-loga-firm/wyniki-wyszukiwania/14032.png" alt="logo" class="offer-logo__image"></a></div><div class="offer-details__text"><h3 class="offer-details__title"><a class="offer-details__title-link" href="/praca/data-engineer-for-bixby-voice-assistant-krakow,oferta,7201566">Data Engineer for Bixby Voice Assistant</a></h3><p class="offer-company"><span class="offer-company__link-wrapper"></li>
```

And it's possible to extract hidden content by web scraper(BeautifulSoup4)?

Comment: Please include yuor current coding attempt. Also, can you share the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden content is usually generated via JS. If you make a request to the webpage, it will not contain hidden HTML because the page has to be loaded in a browser for the hidden content to be loaded. We can get around this by using selenium web browser to actually open the page and then get the HTML from the rendered page.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('example-url.com')
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features='html.parser')

hidden_divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'offer offer--normal'})
```

Of course, we would need the URL you are looking at to actually test this but this is how it generally works.